# can someone please help me with this update table

Tags: php

I would like to update my database table with first name and last name where email is equal to session email but I cant update the table where the email is equal to the signed in email of the user please help me.

```
<?php

 session_start();

 if(!session_is_registered(email)){

header("location: login.html");

}?>
<?php
echo"<a href = logout.php> Logout </a>";  
?>
<?php
include('config.php');

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) {

echo "Welcome &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$_SESSION['email']."";

} 


 ?>
 <?php
  $dbhost = 'localhost';
   $dbuser = 'user';
    $dbpass = 'password';
   $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
  if(! $conn )
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

  $sql="UPDATE nametable SET fname='$fname', lname='$lname' WHERE email='" . $_SESSION      ['email'] . "'";

   echo $row['fname']." - ".$row['lname']. "<br />";
      if($result) {
       echo "success"; 
   } else { 
         echo "no success"; 
    }

  mysql_select_db('db');
  $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
  if(! $retval )
   {
   die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
  echo "Updated data successfully\n";
 mysql_close($conn);

 ?>
```

this id the data that is going to be submitted depending on the first name and last name that is is going to be updated don't worry about the other tags I just put this together to get an idea of what is going to be updated on the above code please tell me what I did wrong

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <title>Update a Record in MySQL Database</title>
   </head>
   <body>

  <form method="post" action="update1.php">
    <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
    <td width="100"> first name</td>
    <td><input name="fname" type="text" id="fname"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td width="100">last name</td>
   <td><input name="lname" type="text" id="lname"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="100"> </td>
 <td> </td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
             <td width="100"> </td>
      <td>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
     </td>
     </tr>
       </table>
       </form>

       </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: What happens currently? Does it update, not update, any mysql errors? etc

Comment: the new data fname and lname do not get saved to the table where email in the table

Comment: Have you wraped your input elements inside `<form>` tag?

Comment: You never create $fname or any of them.

Comment: where does that go ? im new this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need qoutes `""` around strings in your SQL

```
$sql="UPDATE nametable SET fname='$fname', lname='$lname' WHERE email='" . $_SESSION      ['email'] . "'";
```

should be

```
$sql='UPDATE nametable SET fname="'.$fname.'", lname="'.$lname.'" WHERE email="'.$_SESSION['email'].'"';
```

next, you are not executing the query at all. Think you in the following

```
  echo $row['fname']." - ".$row['lname']. "<br />";
      if($result) {
       echo "success"; 
   } else { 
         echo "no success"; 
   }
```

really mean :

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_affected_rows()>-1) {
   // success
   // do here what you want
}
```

Comment: nothing happened the fname and lname were not submitted to the table

Answer (score 0):

I think session_is_registered function is already deprecated so instead of

```
session_is_registered('email')
```

You might want to use:

```
if ( isset( $_SESSION['email'] ) ){}
```

and in one page of php you can only have 1 session_start() function.

If it's still not working, try to debug your code by printing out the $sql variable.

Let me know if that help.

Comment: no I didn't help I just keeps going back to login every time I submit the data